# Custom django runserver command which establish ssh tunel before running server

Tags: django, ssh-tunnel

My application use database which is on another server. To increase security, access to db server was restricted only for specified production servers.

However sometimes I need to have access to this db, when running development environment from my localhost.

For now a simply run in another console before running server:

`ssh tunnel@server-with-access-to-db.com -L 12345:localhost:3306`

..which works great, however I need to remember to do that.

I am wondering how to write custom `runserver` which will establish tunnel automatically, and what is important, will close that tunnel after server will be shut down.

I know that in the future VPN will be much better, however it is not possible for now.

I will be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: In order to execute commands on a remote host, I recommend looking into [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/).

Answer (score 1):

FYI: one part of writing custom `runserver` command is extending it. You can use [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645051/there-is-a-way-to-add-features-to-an-existing-django-command) to do so.