# Django app initialization process

Tags: python, django, deployment, development-environment

There is a set of functions that I need to carry out during the start of my server. Regardless of path whether that be "/", "/blog/, "/blog/post". For developments purposes I'd love for this script to run every time I run `python manage.py runserver` and for production purposes I would love this script to run during deployment. Anyone know how this can be done?

My script is scraping data off and making a call to Facebook's Graph API with python and some of its libraries.

Comment: Have you considered using celery ? (http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django/)

Comment: It depends on what is your script intended for !

Comment: Scraping data and making a call to Facebook's Graph API with python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [custom management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/):

1. Create command for initialization:

   e.g. `app/management/commands/initialize_some_stuff.py`

   ```
   from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand


   class Command(BaseCommand):
       help = 'Description of your command.'

       def handle(self, *args, **options):
           # Add your initialization here.
           print 'What should I initialize?'
   ```
2. Create command for running server during development:

   e.g. `app/management/commands/rundevserver.py`

   ```
   import os

   from django.core.management import call_command
   from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand


   class Command(BaseCommand):
       help = 'Description of your command.'

       def handle(self, *args, **options):
           if not os.environ.get('RUN_MAIN'):
               call_command('initialize_some_stuff', *args, **options)
           call_command('runserver', *args, **options)
   ```
3. Call `./manage.py rundevserver` instead of `./manage.py runserver` during development.
4. Add `./manage.py initialize_some_stuff` to your deployment script.

As an alternative to 3rd clause you can also [override default `runserver` command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6645051/5098707) and conditionally call `./manage.py initialize_some_stuff` from it:

1. Add additional imports:

   ```
   import os

   from django.conf import settings
   ```
2. Override `handle` method:

   ```
   def handle(self, *args, **options):
       if os.environ.get('RUN_MAIN') and settings.DEBUG:
           call_command('initialize_some_stuff', *args, **options)
       super(Command, self).handle(*args, **options)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the quickest (if not most elegant) solution would be to call 'python manage.py runserver' at the end of your script.